# Cannot change page background colour from the toolbar

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word-2007

Office 2007 loaded ok. However in using word the page background is black and the text is white when trying to change page colour to white from the toolbar nothing happens it will not change to any other colour?

I have tried loading Works and the word program in that is the same 'Black background and white text impossible to change?
Office 2007 installed on another computer running windows 10 and works fine?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  If possible, could you add a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings in the Start Menu

Click on Ease of Access

On the left click on High Contrast

Check if a High Contrast theme is selected

If it's so select None and click on Apply